# Access Is Denied when Debugging Visual Studio 2022 Preview

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022

When attempting to debug, any solution/project, in Visual Studio 2022 preview I'm receiving "Access Is Denied"

The directory that the solution exists has all the correct permissions for my user account as well as administrators. I have also tried while running Visual Studio as admin. The output exe will also register Access Is Denied if I try to run it directly, outside visual studio. I can move the exe to another directory and still receive the Access Is Denied message.

I utilize Windows 10 version 21H2, I login using an Azure Active Directory account.

My project paths live in C:\Users(MyAzureName)\Version Control\

[image: Debug Error]

[image: Console Error]

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the cause of this problem. Our cloud antivirus solution was submitting applications from my Version Control directory to quarantine without notifying me. I have excluded this path from my AV scanning and now my debugging is functioning as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F5 worked once. For corp managed systems, the option to change the virus checker settings are limited. Any other ideas appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

**try below**

- Copy your project folder to  C:\Users%userprofile%\source\repos
- Open the project from the above path in VS2022 or your version.
- Try with CTRL+F5 (if you see access denied, try again)
- Next try with F5